# How to get last OPTION from SELECT list using XPath - Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using this selector but it is giving error

`//*[@id="quantity"]/option/[last()-1]`

How do I select last OPTION?

I am using Scrapy Framework.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have an extra `/` before the `[` making the XPath expression *invalid*. Remove it:

```
//*[@id="quantity"]/option[last()-1]
```

Note that you can also solve it using Python/Scrapy:

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="quantity"]/option')[-1].extract()
```

Or, in a *CSS selector* form:

```
response.css('#quantity option:last-child').extract_first()
response.css('#quantity option')[-1].extract()
```

Comment: where did you find `extract_one` method? It isnt in Doc. Isnt?

Comment: also can you look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938322/python-scrapy-cookies-are-not-working-but-working-in-php-curl-code

Comment: @Umair ah my bad, it is `extract_first()`, too much `BeautifulSoup` these days :) Thanks